# Working with sparse data in numpy and sklearn

Tags: regression, scikit-learn, sparse, numpy

I have a time series dataset geenrated from some electrophysiological data.  I have a frequncy dataset and the matrix is quite sparse but huge, like it contains 0.005 s time bins for 2000+ neurons recorded over an hour so the matrix is huge.  I am using this to train regressions in sklearn and I was wondering if there were ways to represent the matrix more efficiently?  Tons of the data is taken up by 0 values.

Specifically I will be using these two functions on the matrix,
https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.cross_decomposition.CCA.html
https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.linear_model.ElasticNetCV.html

Will scipy.sparse run with sklearn functions?
https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/sparse.html